# (Python) Datetime far in the future?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am looking forward to deal with dates that are quite far in the future in a python module (maybe a million years from now)

Fortunately, the datetime module deals perfectly with dates.
Unfortunately it seems that its upper limit is year 10 000.

Even though I could simply make :

```
dt = (year1 - year0)*3600.*24.*365.25 # dt in seconds
```

within acceptable accuracy, I would like to use some "datetime-like" objects that can deal with "infinite" time (let's assume 10 billion years is infinite to the scale of earth time)

Thanks

Comment: Their idea is to start from 0 years once they hit 10,000, in the future, nobody wants to have a calendar that says this is 2000000th year. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem

Comment: Python's datetime.MAXYEAR = 9999. If you want to use more than that, you will have to create your own data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module just codifies the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), which is only valid from 1582 (at the earliest, 1752 for US and UK) and until we switch to another system.

I'd suggest just using the number of years (or seconds, or maybe some [natural unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)) after some given epoch (e.g. "the big bang" or 2000-01-01T00:00Z)

Your choice would be determined by what operations you want to do with these "dates" and what constraints need to be maintained.

Also note that 10 billion years is only about twice the age of the earth, and hence this seems to be far too close to be "infinite"!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess i'll just make my own class then. 
Given the use I intend for this, twice the age of the Earth is more than enough ! (worst case possible, geological time needed ; more likely a few hundred thousands)